# Nautilus script to perform one operation on multiple selected files?

Tags: shell-script, nautilus

I have a Nautilus script that I would like to modify so it performs a single operation using multiple selected files as input. Can someone please explain how to achieve this?

I tried `command $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` and what the script does is execute  `command file1`, then `command file2` as two discrete operations. That doesn't work for my use case, instead I need the script to execute `command file1 file2`.

If it matters, I am using it with the command `align_image_stack` which needs 2 or more image files as input. I started Nautilus from a terminal to see error messages and I get *"align_image_stack: At least two files need to be specified"*. I've tested a few commands shown below, but all produce the same error message. I think the problem is the variable `$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` produces newlines, but I don't know how else to capture selected file paths.

```
align_image_stack "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS"
align_image_stack $(echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS")
align_image_stack printf("$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS")
echo -n "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | xargs -I align_image_stack "{}"
```

Comment: Have you tried  `xargs -L 1` or `echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | while IFS= read -r filepath; do align_image_stack "$filepath" ; done`  ?

Comment: `xargs -L 1` produces the error *"Precondition violation / Unable to open file '{}'"* and the second produces the same error as before, *"align_image_stack: At least two files need to be specified"*.

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to get `$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` working, but here is what did work instead:

```
command $(echo -n "$@")
```

I believe this is called command substitution, and the "$@" characters insert all selected files into the command together as input, with the -n argument suppressing newlines after echo lists them.

If you ever need to align and fuse together a group of bracketed photos, here's a Nautilus script which is now tested and working perfectly. It outputs the finished product to your desktop (file name is the current time) and cleans up all temporary files after:

```
#!/bin/bash
align_image_stack -a BATCH -C $(echo -n "$@") && enfuse -o ~/Desktop/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%T').tif BATCH*.tif && rm BATCH*.tif
```